# Como Extraer el código de un archivo JavaScript para compartirlo en un archivo HTML

Tags: javascript, html, script, dom

Hola estoy con un pequeño inconveniente algo muy tonto tal vez, pero no consigo una respuesta.

Estoy haciendo una página con pequeños snippets, recordatorios sobre JavaScript pero necesito obtener el contenido de los archivos .js para compartirlos en la página principaly poder formatearlos con la libreria highlight.js [image: ejemplo de la página] en estos momentos lo estoy haciendo pero de manera manual, copio el código en una variable escapo los caracteres y luego los imprimo en el DOM, pero no es la solución optima. Me pudieran guiar para poder hacerlo de forma automática, obtener el código de el archivo *.js muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow, dos cosas: 1-Te recomiendo que reemplaces la foto del codigo por un bloque de código para que sea mas legible y se pueda copia/pegar de manera rápida y poder replicar tu error. 2- te recomiendo leer el apartado [¿Como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que formules mejor tus preguntas.

Comment: Exacto, no se entiende directamente la pregunta.